# spark for typescript syntax

Tags: typescript, chalk

I try to use Spark with TypeScript but when I write this

```
Spark.get("/facture", (req, res) => { 
    chalk.red('Hello test');
    chalk.green('Hello word');
})
```

It return me undefined but when I write only 1 line it works

```
Spark.get("/facture", (req, res) => 
    chalk.green('Hello word');
)
```

I think that the problem come from the syntax. Someone can help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using arrow functions, if they are one liners you can omit the { } and the value returned by the expression will be the return value of the function.

In essence:

```js
Spark.get("/facture", (req, res) => 
    chalk.green('Hello word');
)
```

Transpiles to:

```js
Spark.get("/facture", function (req, res) {
    return chalk.green('Hello word');
});
```

However when you have more than one statement and you make a body for the arrow function you must manually return the value as you would in normal functions.

You can easily see it when transpiled.

```js
Spark.get("/facture", (req, res) => { 
    chalk.red('Hello test');
    chalk.green('Hello word');
})
```

Transpiles to:

```js
Spark.get("/facture", function (req, res) {
    chalk.red('Hello test');
    chalk.green('Hello word');
});
```

If you want to return something you have to write the return statement:

```js
Spark.get("/facture", (req, res) => { 
    chalk.red('Hello test');
    return chalk.green('Hello word');
})
```

So it ends up like this in javascript:

```js
Spark.get("/facture", function (req, res) {
    chalk.red('Hello test');
    return chalk.green('Hello word');
});
```

You can see the examples in the playground [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=Spark.get(%22%2Ffacture%22%2C%20(req%2C%20res)%20%3D%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chalk.green('Hello%20word')%3B%0D%0A)%0D%0A%0D%0ASpark.get(%22%2Ffacture%22%2C%20(req%2C%20res)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chalk.red('Hello%20test')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chalk.green('Hello%20word')%3B%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0ASpark.get(%22%2Ffacture%22%2C%20(req%2C%20res)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chalk.red('Hello%20test')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20chalk.green('Hello%20word')%3B%0D%0A%7D)) and learn more about arrow functions on the MDN page for them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).